# How can I subtract a value from all values in the imported CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, subtraction

I have read in a CSV file with one column. The column contains almost 300 rows of different values. From these values I want to subtract a certain value `b=0.157`. These new approx. 300 values should be saved in a new CSV file (array). How can I do this?

This is the csv - file: **wearable.csv**

```
    right,
    0.960, 
    1.079, 
    1.019, 
    1.028, 
    1.086, 
    1.042, 
    .....
    .....
    .....
```

and the part of my code, where I read in the csv - file:
`wearable = pd.read_csv("wearable.csv")`

Now I want to subtract b from all values in the csv - file. So that I end up with new values which are saved in a new CSV file. How can I reach this? Could someone please explain this to me? Thank you.

The final result (new CSV file) should look like this:

**wearable_new.csv**

```
right,
0.803,
0.922,
0.862,
0.871,
0.929,
0.885,
.....
.....
.....
```

Maybe I have to do a for - loop. Maybe someone could explain to me some kind of sample how to do it. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
I do not understand why this question was closed. I have already received (see below) an answer of my question before the question was closed. This answer also helped me. I did not need another one.

Comment: `(pd.read_csv('path/to/input.csv').right - 0.157).to_csv('path/to/output.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the broacasting property of `numpy` (`pandas` is based on `numpy` arrays) and simply subtract a constant value from the dataframe.

**Edit**: adding the part to save to file

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

b = 0.157
df = pd.DataFrame({'right': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)})

df

    right
0   0.00
1   0.25
2   0.50
3   0.75
4   1.00

df - b


    right
0   -0.157
1   0.093
2   0.343
3   0.593
4   0.843

(df - b).to_csv('/path/output.csv', index=False, line_terminator = ',\n')
```